# JS - creating table dynamically

Tags: javascript

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link href="mycss.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">

        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>

        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    </head>
    <body>

    <div class="container">

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
                <h4>REGISTER FORM</h4>
                <p><small>Please, fill in all the fields.</small></p>

                <form id="register-form">
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="name">Name</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Enter user name" required>
                  </div>

                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="dof">Date of Birth</label>
                    <input type="date" class="form-control" id="dof" placeholder="mm/dd/yyyy" required>
                  </div>

                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="email">Email</label>
                    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Enter email">
                  </div>

                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="tel">Phone number</label>
                    <input type="tel" class="form-control" id="tel" placeholder="Enter Phone number">
                  </div>

                  <button id="save-button" class="btn btn-primary pull-right" onclick="save();">Save</button>
                </form>

            </div>      
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
                <table class="table">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Name</th>
                            <th>Date of Birth</th>
                            <th>Email</th>
                            <th>Phone number</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody></tbody>
                </table>
            </div>      
        </div>

    </div>

    <script>
      $( function() {
        $( "#dof" ).datepicker();
      } );
    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    function save() {
        var tbody = document.getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0];
        var name = document.getElementById('name').value;
        var dof = document.getElementById('dof').value;     
        var email = document.getElementById('email').value;
        var tel = document.getElementById('tel').value;

        var tr = document.createElement('tr');
        var columns = [name, dof, email, tel]

        for (var i = 0; i < columns.length; i++) {
            var td = document.createElement("td");
            var text = document.createTextNode(columns[i]);
            td.appendChild(text);
            tr.appendChild(td);
        }

        tbody.appendChild(tr);
    };      
    </script>

    </body>
    </html>
```

My save() function doesn't work.

P.S. Guys :) do not read it..this is for support service ;) It is annoying a lot.. I mean the popup that says that It looks like mostly code...bla bla

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that the form submits, thereby reloading the page and resetting everything.

This you can solve by calling `preventDefault()` on the event object. For that you have to change two things to the `save` function:

1. Add a function argument to capture the event object, let's call it *e*:

   ```
   function save(e) {
   ```
2. Call `preventDefault` somewhere in the function, but it is common to put this near the end:

   ```
       e.preventDefault();
   }
   ```

This is not all. Now you have to make sure the event object is passed to your function. There are at least two ways:

1. If you stick to the `onclick` attribute, then change it to include the special `event` object:

   ```
   <button ... onclick="save(event);">
   ```
2. Many regard it better practice to not use the `onclick` attribute at all. In that case remove that attribute, and attach the event handler through JavaScript:

   ```
   $('#save-button').click(save);
   ```

   In that case the event object is passed automatically.

#### Further remarks

As you are using jQuery, why not use it consistently? You have many native DOM calls in your code, like `document.getElementsByTagName`, for which jQuery has much nicer equivalents.

Taking it all together your code could look like this:

```
$('#save-button').click(function (e) {
    var columns = [
        $('#name').val(),
        $('#dof').val(),   
        $('#email').val(),
        $('#tel').val()
    ];
    var $tr = $('<tr>');
    for (var i = 0; i < columns.length; i++) {
        $("<td>").text(columns[i]).appendTo($tr);
    }
    $('tbody:first').append($tr);
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to load your created function, like that.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
       save();
    });

    function save() {
        var tbody = document.getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0];
        var name = document.getElementById('name').value;
        var dof = document.getElementById('dof').value;     
        var email = document.getElementById('email').value;
        var tel = document.getElementById('tel').value;

        var tr = document.createElement('tr');
        var columns = [name, dof, email, tel]

        for (var i = 0; i < columns.length; i++) {
            var td = document.createElement("td");
            var text = document.createTextNode(columns[i]);
            td.appendChild(text);
            tr.appendChild(td);

        }

        tbody.appendChild(tr);

    };      
    </script>
```

Comment: It has worked, but only partially.. when I hit button I can see how the data is appeared in the table..but for very short time..then everything is disappeared